# Can we write Spring in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to know whether we can write code for Spring and make use of that Spring framework, if i work in Grails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grails is already based on Java, Groovy, Spring, and Hibernate.  You've been using it without knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reuse the bean that implemented in your spring application. You can integrate it with the usual spring XML file or use Spring DSL

For further reference check http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html

Comment: I read the question as being in the opposite direction: Can I use a Grails service in a Spring application. Correct me, if I'm wrong.